# How to allow and expect a compiler warning in Rust?

Tags: rust

Sometimes during development I would like to allow warnings. For example, for `dead_code`. Yet, in CI and pre_commit git hooks, I have `RUSTFLAGS="--deny warnings"`.

So I'm thinking that what I would like is an attribute such as

```rust
#[expect(dead_code)]
fn foo() {
    todo!();
}
```

It would work similar to TypesScript's [`@ts-expect-error`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) and yet be more specific, expecting a specific list of warnings.

Not sure whether it would make sense for expecting errors, as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is supported experimentally. The RFC is called [Lint Reasons](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2383-lint-reasons.md). The form is exactly what you would expect: `#[expect(lint)]`.

```rust
#![feature(lint_reasons)]

#[expect(dead_code)]
fn foo() {
    todo!();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2dd9ab7546a82209d6a3c1b997d63a8d).

If the expectation is not fulfilled, a warning is raised. You can `#[deny(unfulfilled_lint_expectations)]` to make it into an error.

If you only want to allow the warning (but not warn when it is not raised), use [`#[allow(lint)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#lint-check-attributes):

```rust
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn foo() {
    todo!();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67a853369a15f17e1c361d4096ab9cab).